# MySQL Update every value where x

Tags: mysql

How can I update every value in a line where x?

e.g.

```
test table values ('name', 'age')
UPDATE test SET name='alex' //update one value
```

but I want to update name & age with one query

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: An `UPDATE` with no `WHERE` clause updates *all* rows.  `UPDATE test SET name='alex', age=42`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will update ALL the records in the table

```
UPDATE test SET name='alex', age='40'
```

if you want to update just one/some records you can add a condition:

```
UPDATE test SET name='alex', age='40' WHERE name='John'
```

for example will update every record with the name John setting name as Alex and age 40.

You can start from here to build the queries you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test SET name='alex', age=21
```

Note that this will update ALL rows.

```
UPDATE test SET name='alex', age=21 WHERE id=1
```

Will only update the row where id is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use UPDATE and WHERE.

```
UPDATE test set name='new_name', age='new_age' WHERE id='id_value'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test
SET name = 'alex', age = 37
WHERE hairColor = 'red'
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp
SQL UPDATE Syntax:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```